# Is there a way to set the fold symbol in sublimetext read only?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

If I delete the fold symbol in sublimetext the whole folded text is deleted?
I would prefer that the fold symbol unfolds before you can delete it (like in vim).
[image]

Comment: I don't think making folds read only is possible. However unfolding them, if you are right behind them and press backspace should not be that complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you want to have the behavior, that it automatically unfolds if you are behind a fold and press backspace. This is easy to archive (in version 3125+) you just need to add a context and a command.

Create a plugin via *Tools >> Developer >> New Plugin...*, paste, and save:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class UnfoldBeforeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        for sel in view.sel():
            # fold the position before the selection
            view.unfold(sublime.Region(sel.b - 1))


class IsBehindFoldContext(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_query_context(self, view, key, operator, operand, match_all):
        if key != "is_behind_fold":
            return

        quantor = all if match_all else any

        result = quantor(
            view.is_folded(sel) and view.is_folded(sublime.Region(sel.b - 1))
            for sel in view.sel()
        )

        if operator == sublime.OP_EQUAL:
            result = result == operand
        elif operator == sublime.OP_NOT_EQUAL:
            result = result != operand
        else:
            raise Exception("Operator type not supported")

        return result
```

add this to your keymap:

```js
{
    "keys": ["backspace"],
    "command": "unfold_before",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "selection_empty" },
        { "key": "is_behind_fold", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
}
```

Now you should be fine.

Comment: Great! Thank you! This makes Sublimetext perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Simply open the fold and any custom fold will disappear. With custom fold I mean folds inserted with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `]`.

Comment: I am looking for settings or a plugin solution which makes all fold symbols readonly. In Vim deleting a fold symbol with backspace opens it.

Comment: Well, then I'm afraid I can't help you. I haven't found any plugin of that kind.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I really like the design of sublime! But this is the only issue other editors like vim are way better or just slightly better eg. visual code ... Anyway maybe someone will come up with an idea